# составить новую строку из уникальных символов заданной строки

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки, python-3.x

Требуется вести с клавиатуры строку и после сформировать новую из тех символов, которые встречаются в ней только один раз.

Comment: списками, причем, не пользоваться

Comment: задание выполнил, просто нужно было указать, что тут требуется метод count и на этом всем спасибо

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. У нас не принято выполнять задания за учащихся. Пожалуйста, решайте задачи самостоятельно и задавайте вопросы по конкретным ошибкам или затруднениям.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: суть вопроса понятна, вот к примеру [решение](https://gist.github.com/zed/e9b797aa0d2d73a8eed61331660c58f0) (ещё [схожая задача](https://gist.github.com/zed/dc4c5fc396c36373bfc68e91402cfcf8)). Не нужно фиктивные причины закрытия использовать. Если вы не согласны, что проблему [работа за автора](https://goo.gl/mXSV8N) не решить, закрывая вопросы, то опубликуйте на Мете свой ответ с предложением о введении такой причины закрытия с конкретной формулировкой (если на чужих ошибках не получается учиться, можно попробовать свои совершать).

Comment: @jfs я вижу тут четыре отдельных задачи: ввести строку с клавиатуры; посчитать <s>символы в строке</s> объекты в списке и положить результат, например,  в словарь `символ: количество`; отфильтровать из словаря ключи по условию на значение; объединить результат в строку. Непонятно, что именно у автора не получается сделать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если вы пройдёте по ссылке, которую я дал или посмотрите на [собственное решение автора вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595984/23044), то увидите что никаких словарей здесь не нужно. В самом вопросе также словари не упомянуты. Из ответа и комментариев автора следует, что помощь со вводом также не нужна. В заголовке вопроса (мной составленным) на основе текста вопроса, комментариев и ответа автора вопроса—кратко выражена его суть. Вы как модератор демонстрируете непотребное поведение—модератор должен обрабатывать исключения из правил, а не свои создавать.

Comment: я спросил как и нашел ответ - методом count, что тут непонятного

Comment: @rosharh не обязательно `count()` использовать, посмотрите на [ссылки из моего комментария наверху  с примерами кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595962/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment804074_595962)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'qwertyqwertyufgfghjj' # символы "u","h" встречаются один раз
set_s = set(s)
res = ''.join([x for x in set_s if s.count(x) == 1])
print(res)
```

upd: без использования списков

```
s = 'qwertyqwertyufgfghjj' # символы "u" и "h" встречаются один раз
set_s = set(s)
res = ''
for x in set_s:
    if s.count(x) == 1:
        res +=x
print(res)
```

Comment: а как без перевода в списки?

Answer (score 0):

[count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

```
stri = input()
result = ''.join(char for char in set(stri) if stri.count(char) == 1)
```

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
stri = input()
counter_dict = Counter(stri)
result = ''.join(key for key in counter_dict if counter_dict[key] == 1)
```

result в порядке ввода - [index](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index), [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
result = ''.join(sorted(result, key=stri.index))
```

Comment: не всё так просто, тут нужно обойтись без использования списков

Comment: как хорошо, что я только начал постигать программирование, в частности питон. и так как я еще понимаю только малую часть, то просто не могу осмыслить, что в этом коде написано. поэтому и не могу придать значение твоему мастерству. лол

Comment: @rosharh: код в ответе работает, но стиль является неудовлетворительным: ненужное использование `lambda`, слишком короткие имена везде, уминание кода в одну строку без нужды. Отсутствие описания/разделения: в частности не упоминается, что первое решение это квадратичный алгоритм, а второе решение—линейный. Для крошечного ввода это не важно, но так как ответы на Stack Overflow рассчитаны не только на одного автора, но и для будущих читателей это следует упомянуть. По отдельности больших грехов нет, но по совокупности (не первый раз мне приходится про отсутствие описания говорить), ставлю минус.

Answer (score -1):

```
s=input('введите текст: ')
v=''
for i in s:
    if s.count(i)==1:
        v+=i
print(v)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?